# H2 Database triggers

Tags: h2

generally, when you use H2 database you have to create custom class and implement method "fire" to write Trigger.

For my project I am using batches for inserts. I need to use trigger to make a kind of complex data integrity check on the table I want to insert into, which is not possible using CHECK. So I have to make a select statement in the trigger method to make a check.

Since there could be many inserts I would like to avoid many server roundtrips for each trigger select statement(that's why I am using batches for inserts). Does H2 database sends request to DB from "fire" method everytime if I make a select statement there or is this trigger method somehow integrated into database engine itself ?

Thanks,
Lubos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers are executed on the server side, so the are no server roundtrips when executing triggers.